# Xamarin Forms - How to create custom render to give TableSection the default iOS Footer?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to add the default iOS footer to the tablesection in the tableview in Xamarin Forms. How can I go about doing this? I assume a customer renderer but I'm only reading that this can be done for Tableview?

To show an example, the following image is from Xcode storyboards when I enter the footer text on a static cell.

[image: Tablesection footer view shown here]

Comment: did you find a way to do it? mind to share? trying to do the exact same thing

Comment: @BartCalixto Sorry, Stackoverflow didn't alert me to this comment. I was able to use the answer below to get it working by overriding TitleForFooter and returning the string I wanted for each section. Works exactly as the native version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Custom renderer is right, but you will have to use a custom renderer for the entire `TableView`. From there, you will need to override the `TableViewModelRenderer` and then the `GetViewForFooter` method in that `ModelRenderer`. Here's something that might help get you started:

```
public class FooterTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
            return;

        var tableView = Control as UITableView;
        var formsTableView = Element as TableView;
        tableView.WeakDelegate = new CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer (formsTableView);
    }


    private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
    {
        public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
        {
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return new UILabel()
            {
                Text = TitleForFooter(tableView, section), // or use some other text here
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
            };
        }

    }
}
```

As mentioned in my comments below, you can alternatively override other methods in your `TableViewModelRenderer`:

```
        public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return 10;
        }

        public override string TitleForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return "This is the title for this given section";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try this tonight and let you know how it goes. This will be my first custom renderer ever but I think I understand what you are doing. It seems you did a bunch of stuff that eventually exposes the native UITable Delegate functions. If that's the case I think I should be good.

Comment: Yeah the `TableViewModelRenderer` actually inherits `UITableViewSource`, so you get all the delegate overrides there. I have a blog post on how to do custom section header views for a `TableView` in iOS here: https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/21/xamarin-tips-xamarin-forms-ios-custom-tableview-section-titles/

You can use essentially the same set up, but override the footer rather than header.

Comment: I was able to get something on the screen. It put a footer on every section but I think I know what I need to fix that. Only issue is the text isn't what I was expecting. I've edited the question to add an image. That image was taken by going to storyboard in Xcode and making a static table and then selecting the section and adding a footer text in the options on the right. It made a grey label on the bottom. Is there a way to get that or am I going to have to play with uilabel styles to match that? Since it's there I feel like it might be built in.

Comment: I used -(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 in my app when it was pure Xcode, but I'm not getting that in any autocomplete in Xamarin.

Comment: I'm thinking your TitleForFooter might be the same function but it is not getting hit via a breakpoint. It seems to just skip that method.

Comment: Yeah, `TitleForFooter` is the same as `titleForFooterInSection`. However, you should also override that method if you want to actually get a text value out of it, since the Xamarin.Forms `TableView` doesn't have a footer property, the default `TitleForFooter` in your `ModelRenderer` will return null. That's why I put a comment in the code saying `// or use some other text here`. This is where you will have to use some custom logic to get what footer text you want. Also, you will have to style the inner `UILabel` to get it looking like the default, OR use some of the other overrides.

Comment: You can override `WillDisplayFooterView`, `TitleForFooter`, and `GetHeightForFooter` instead of doing `GetViewForFooter`. Doing that should give you the default `UILabel` that normally comes with the `UITableView`. Adding examples as an edit to my answer.

Comment: I know this is an old anaswer but i don't see any overridebale methods in TableViewModelRenderer that are related to Footers. Did they move them elsewhere?