# Xamarin Forms - How to create custom render to give TableSection on Android a footer?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, tableview

I want to add the default Android footer to the tablesection in the tableview in Xamarin Forms. How can I go about doing this? I believe I need a tableview custom renderer but I'm not sure past the point of making it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your other question [Xamarin Forms - How to create custom render to give TableSection the default iOS Footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036165/xamarin-forms-how-to-create-custom-render-to-give-tablesection-the-default-ios), I'm not sure whether you want to add footer to the whole `TableView` or to each `TableSection` of `TableView`.

If you want to add footer to each `TableSection`, I suggest just to add a customized `TextCell` as footer in each `TableSection` since `TableSection` can have multiple `Cell` children, but if you want to add footer to `TableView`, you can for example code like this:

```
public class TableViewWithFooterRenderer : TableViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                //Add footer to the whole TableView
                var lv = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
                var footerview = ((LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService))
                    .Inflate(Resource.Layout.TableViewFooter, null, false);
                lv.AddFooterView(footerview);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created a view for footer, as you can also use other views. My footer view is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="7dp">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:text="This is footer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**

`TableView` is [rendered as ListView](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/TableViewRenderer.cs) in Android platform, since there is no native method in Android platform to directly add footer to each item of `ListView`, as I suggested, we can manually add a customized `TextCell` or `ViewCell` as footer for each item. As you can see from the source code of [TableSection](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/TableSection.cs), it's a `ObservableCollection` of objects.

For example:

```
 <TableSection Title="Section 1 Title">
     <TextCell Text="TextCell Text" Detail="TextCell Detail"></TextCell>
     <ViewCell IsEnabled="False">
         <Grid>
             <Label Text="This is footer" />
         </Grid>
     </ViewCell>
 </TableSection>
```

I didn't customized the style of `ViewCell` here, you may try your style on it.

Comment: This is close. I want a footer to each tablesection, NOT the whole tableview. Looking at your answer, I would want to be able to inflate that footview and change the text and add it to each section. How could I accomplish that? I want it as close as the iOS version I have in the other question which has the default iOS footer for each section with different text.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444, yeah, I understand, but as I said, we can add customized cell into each tablesection as footer, I updated my answer, there is no native method in android to add a footer to each tablesection in android platform.

Comment: I gave it a shot only showing the view cell on android and uwp and it seems to work. The last cell on android however has a bottom border and I'm not sure how to get rid of that but I'm close enough.