# How can I create a custom TableView that will allow me to specify footer height and text and space out the text just like in the iOS settings page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I saw this example:

[Xamarin Forms - How to create custom render to give TableSection the default iOS Footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036165/xamarin-forms-how-to-create-custom-render-to-give-tablesection-the-default-ios)

It does 75% of what I am looking for with this code:

```
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TableView), typeof(Japanese.iOS.TableViewCustomRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    public class TableViewCustomRenderer : TableViewRenderer
    {
        UITableView tableView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
                return;

            var tableView = Control as UITableView;
            var formsTableView = Element as TableView;
            tableView.WeakDelegate = new CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(formsTableView);
        }


        void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
        {
            public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
            {
            }

            public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                return 10;
            }

            public override string TitleForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
            {
                return "This is the title for this given section";
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**1.** However what I would like is to be able to extend TableView so that I am able to put in the XAML some way to set or leave unset the footer text and height. Something like:

```
<ExtTableView FooterText="abc" FooterHeight="50". ..
```

**2.** From experiments with the code above I tried hardcoding in some text and realize that there is no spacing set. So I would also like to find out if there is a way to set the spacing and font so it appears just like in the iOS settings pages?

Could someone suggest how I could go about creating what I am looking for which is I guess something like an ExtTableView class that can accept additional arguments.

Comment: So you know how to change the footer height but just want to be able to pass the value in XAML code?

Comment: Yes I am not sure how I could do that in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hankide said , I just provide more details.

> 1. However what I would like is to be able to extend TableView so that I am able to put in the XAML some way to set or leave unset the footer text and height.

**Create MyTableView that inherits from TableView**

```
public class MyTableView : TableView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FooterHeightProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create("FooterHeight", typeof(string), typeof(MyTableView), "");

    public string FooterHeight
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FooterHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FooterTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("FooterText", typeof(string), typeof(MyTableView), "");

    public string FooterText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FooterTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Get the value that you set in XMAL and assign them to CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
            return;

        var tableView = Control as UITableView;
        var formsTableView = Element as MyTableView;

        CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer render = new CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(formsTableView);
        render.height = float.Parse(formsTableView.FooterHeight);
        render.text = formsTableView.FooterText;
        tableView.WeakDelegate = render;
    }

    private class CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer : TableViewModelRenderer
    {
        public float height { get; set; }
        public String text { get; set; }


        public CustomFooterTableViewModelRenderer(TableView model) : base(model)
        {
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {

            UIView view = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, tableView.Frame.Width, 50));
            view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

            UILabel label = new UILabel();
            label.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, tableView.Frame.Width, height);
            label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            label.Text = text;
            label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(15);

            view.Add(label);
            return view;
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return 50;
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
    <local:MyTableView FooterHeight="20" FooterText="ABC">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <TextCell Text="22222" ></TextCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </local:MyTableView>
```

> From experiments with the code above I tried hardcoding in some text and realize that there is no spacing set. So I would also like to find out if there is a way to set the spacing and font so it appears just like in the iOS settings pages?

You could override the method `GetViewForFooter` to change the defalut style of footer，find it in the code above .

**My test :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea about creating the custom control. Here's what to do:

1. Create ExtTableView class that inherits from TableView

   ```
   public class ExtTableView : TableView { }
   ```
2. Create BindableProperties for both FooterText and FooterHeight, as outlined [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/#Creating_a_Property).
3. After that you can set the properties in XAML

   ```
   <ExtTableView FooterText="abc" FooterHeight="50" ...
   ```
4. Within the renderer, you can get the values from Element (which points to our Xamarin.Forms ExtTableView).

   ```
   // Modify the native control with these values
   var text = Element.FooterText;
   var height = Element.FooterHeight;
   ```